# Bad performance of Core Data "save" operation on the managedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an iPhone/iPad app which uses Core Data.

In my DB I have only one table, though it's a very large one (about 40 columns).
When i build the DB i create and insert about 13,000 new entities, and then I call 'saveContext'.

```
for (NSArray *singleDiamond in allDiamonds)
{
     @try 
     {
         if (//Some validation)
         {
             Diamond *diamond = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Diamond class]) 
                                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
             //Do setup for diamond...
         }
     }
     @catch (NSException *exception) {NSLog(@"%@",[exception message]);}
 }
NSLog(@"Start Saving Context...");
[self saveContext];
NSLog(@"End Saving Context...");
```

My problem id that only the 'saveContext' method, takes **23 seconds** to execute. That's not acceptable.

Is there something I do wrong?
How can I improve the performance here?

Comment: Please give me idea or suggestion to insert every 100 objects in core data with batch insert for fast performance because In my iPad device, I have more than 6000 contacts and insert in core data with best performance so please help me for solve this issue.

Comment: Similar question with Swift example of batch inserting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034100/memory-leak-with-large-core-data-batch-insert-in-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call **saveContext** several times during the batch insert, and then call **reset** to "forget" the previous inserted managed objects. For example in my case I save the context every 100 objects. Moreover you should create a dedicated context for the import and optimize it (by setting the undomanager to nil, since you don't need to roolback/undo the whole insert).
Read here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html

Comment: Well, i did try to save every "n" items, but I didn't get any significant improvement over saving everything at the end of the process. I tried n {0 , 100 ,1000 , 5000}

Comment: @daveoncode Please give me idea or suggestion to insert every 100 objects in core data with batch insert for fast performance because In my iPad device, I have more than 6000 contacts and insert in core data with best performance so please help me for solve this issue.

Comment: Calling reset had a minimally negative performance impact for me. The best scenario I found was saving every 100 records with no reset.

Answer (score 4):

Saving 13.000 items is going to take a while.

Are the 13.000 items only saved when you first start the app, if so why not just supply the database as a payload with the app.
So that when the database isn't already there just copy the one from the bundle.

Comment: I cant. I'm getting a CSV from the internet and i'm building the DB with it.

Comment: @rckoenes Please give me idea or suggestion to insert every 100 objects in core data with batch insert for fast performance because In my iPad device, I have more than 6000 contacts and insert in core data with best performance so please help me for solve this issue.

Comment: @NikunjR.Jadav You should post your own question, not request code in an answer to other question.