# Memory leak with large Core Data batch insert in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, memory-leaks, bulkinsert

I am inserting tens of thousands of objects into my Core Data entity. I have a single `NSManagedObjectContext` and I am calling `save()` on the managed object context every time I add an object. It works but while it is running, the memory keeps increasing from about 27M to 400M. And it stays at 400M even after the import is finished.

[image]

There are a number of SO questions about batch insert and everyone says to read [Efficiently Importing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html), but it's in Objective-C and I am having trouble finding real examples in Swift that solve this problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are a few things you should change:

- Create a separate `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` managed object context and do your inserts asynchronously in it.
- Don't save after inserting every single entity object. Insert your objects in batches and then save each batch. A batch size might be something like 1000 objects.
- Use `autoreleasepool` and `reset` to empty the objects in memory after each batch insert and save.

Here is how this might work:

```
let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentStoreCoordinator // or wherever your coordinator is

managedObjectContext.performBlock { // runs asynchronously

    while(true) { // loop through each batch of inserts

        autoreleasepool {
            let array: Array<MyManagedObject>? = getNextBatchOfObjects()
            if array == nil { break }
            for item in array! {
                let newObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! MyManagedObject
                newObject.attribute1 = item.whatever
                newObject.attribute2 = item.whoever
                newObject.attribute3 = item.whenever
            }
        }

        // only save once per batch insert
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        managedObjectContext.reset()
    }
}
```

Applying these principles kept my memory usage low and also made the mass insert faster.

[image]

## Further reading

- Efficiently Importing Data *(old Apple docs link is broken. If you can find it, please help me add it.)*
- [Core Data Performance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html)
- [Core Data](http://mobbook.generalassemb.ly/week07/core-data.html) (General Assembly post)

**Update**

The above answer is completely rewritten. Thanks to @Mundi and @MartinR in the comments for pointing out a mistake in my original answer. And thanks to @JodyHagins in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32061397/3681880) for helping me understand and solve the problem.

Comment: It seems in your code you are using the same managed object context, not a new one.

Comment: The managed object context gets recreated at every `while` loop in my example above. The `while` loop represents one batch of inserts, so a single batch uses the same managed object context, but the next batch creates a new one. My problem in the past was that I made the context a class property and never changed it.

Comment: @Suragch: That depends on how the `managedObjectContext` property is implemented in the Application delegate, but the "usual" implementation is a lazy property which creates the context once for the lifetime of the app. In that case you are reusing the same context as Mundi said.

Comment: I wanted to ask more about the meaning of these comments so I opened a new question: [Where should NSManagedObjectContext be created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042637/where-should-nsmanagedobjectcontext-be-created)

Comment: Fantastic - I have everything except the autorelease pool.  Thanks.

Comment: hi can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055953/how-to-speed-up-updating-relationship-among-tables-after-one-or-both-tables-are?noredirect=1#comment90842008_50055953 thanks

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh, I stopped using CoreData because I am developing for Android and iOS and it is easier to just use SQLite directly with both of them.

Comment: "every block submitted through the perform(_:) method gets wrapped in a autorelease pool." You only need the autorelease pool for performAndWait.